# Adding a UIImageView as a subview of UILabel, image not appearing

Tags: ios, uilabel

So, when I do this with a regular old view:

```
UIView *topBlock = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-frameSize.height, frameSize.width, frameSize.height/2)];
[viewController.view addSubview:topBlock];
topBlock.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
topBlock.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BloktLayout"];
UIImageView *topImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:topImage];
topImageView.frame = viewController.view.frame;
[topBlock addSubview:topImageView];
```

I get the nice old image where I want it, in the top view. But the middle view is a UILabel, and when I try the same thing:

```
UILabel *midBar = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(midBarOrigin.x, midBarOrigin.y, midBarWidth, midBarHeight)];
midBar.text = @"Blokt";
midBar.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
midBar.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
midBar.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:80.0f];
[viewController.view addSubview:midBar];
midBar.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
midBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIImage *midImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BloktLayout"];
UIImageView *midImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:midImage];
midImageView.frame = viewController.view.frame;
[midBar addSubview:midImageView];
```

I don't see any image at all in the UILabel. Any help?

Comment: The `UILabel` is a UI element for displaying texts. You should not use it as a container and add subviews to it.

Comment: There is something wrong with the Frames. Can you print the Frames of `midBar` and `midImageView`. and share here.

Comment: @Levi so I should have UIView as the container and add a UILabel and a UIImageView to that?

Comment: @Roshit I don't think there's anything wrong with the frames. As far as the midImageView, the frame is set identically to 2 other UIViews on the same page that are displaying correctly. And as for midBar, it's behaving fine in every other way: I see the text, and label, and frame, exactly where I want them.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced yes, you should do it that way. And in the view you can position them however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue is related to your frames.

Tough to say without additional info. Can you post `viewController.view.frame`, `frameSize`, and `midBarOrigin` / `midBarWidth` / `midBarHeight`?

In the second codeblock, `midBar.clipsToBounds == YES`, but it looks like the `midImageView.frame` is likely very different / outside of `midBar.frame` in which case it wouldn't be visible.

**Edit** Some screenshots would help but aren't necessary

**Edit 2** Note that subviews' origin points are always relative to the coordinate system of their superview, never relative to the coordinate system of any other view in the view heierarchy. This is likely the heart of the issue here. If you do want to convert CGPoints or CGRects from one coordinate system to another there are methods on [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) such as convertRect: and convertPoint: etc.

Comment: The fact is, if I set midImageView.Frame to the exact same values as midBar.frame, it still doesn't work.  And it's actually worse than that: I just changed it from a UILabel to a UIView and it still doesn't work. I have two other UIViews with identical code and they work! Maybe it is a frame issue, as you say, but each of the other views has different frames itself.

Comment: UILabel inherits from UIView so it's okay to add subviews to it. I'm pretty sure the issue is the framing, frames in the posted code look a little funky. If you can post the values for those I mention above I think we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: For what it's worth: viewController.view.frame is the screen size, frameSize is a convenience variable so I don't have to type viewController.view.frame.size, and `float midBarHeight = midBarBottomY - midBarTopY; //about 1/5 of the screen height`  
    `float midBarWidth = frameSize.width*2;`  
    `CGPoint midBarOrigin = CGPointMake(-midBarWidth, midBarTopY);`

Comment: Without seeing a visual of the intended layout, `midImageView.frame = viewController.view.frame` setting the midImageView to the same frame as the viewController seems odd. Try setting it to `(CGRect){0, 0, midBar.size.width, midBar.size.height}` and see what happens (just to ensure it's located completely within its superview).

Comment: As far as putting subviews in UILabels, I've seen it elsewhere on Stack Overview say that subviews shouldn't be added to UILabels. It seems silly to me, but @Levi said that UILabels are controls, not containers, which does make sense.

Comment: Just in case anyone is following along later, Alfie's suggested change would actually read `midImageView.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0, midBar.frame.size.width, midBar.frame.size.height);`

Comment: Yeah, another approach is definitely to add the UILabel and UIImageView to the same superview container (UIView). So wrt that totally agree with @MarcusAdams that this is another option. But it's also acceptable to add an UIImageView to a UILabel. Matter of preference / specific situation I guess. Also, `(CGRect){0, 0, midBar.size.width, midBar.size.height}` is a-okay syntax-wise, an alternative to CGRectMake...

Comment: I tried it, and it at least put an image in the midBar. The thing is, it confuses me, because I have two other oddly-framed UIViews that use the exact same code (setting their UIImageViews to the viewcontroller's frame), and they work just fine. So why not this one? Anyway, the problem with setting the frame to the exact frame of the midBar is that it displays the whole image. I only want to display the middle slice of the image in the midBar. This is what the other UIViews do perfectly: the topBlock displays the top and the bottomBlock displays the bottom. I do appreciate your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33384/discussion-between-alfie-and-le-mot-juiced)

Comment: Right you are--I didn't know how to make a CGRect that way. The correction is still needed to add the frame in between the midBar and the size. I'm not trying to be a jerk, I just hate it myself when I copy code from a post and there's some small error that I have to spend a long time trying to suss. I thought I'd help a future me.

Comment: I'd like to give you credit for zeroing in on the problem, but your answer doesn't say exactly what was wrong, so it wouldn't be very helpful to anyone else. Is there a way you could edit your answer to specify that 0,0 for subviews is always relative to the parent view, not the screen? Then if someone with my same problem comes to this page, they'll get what they need.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder doesn't even let you add a control inside of a UILabel.

Instead, if you wish to group multiple controls, you can add them both as subviews of a UIView.

In other words, your image view and label can share the same superview, but the image view cannot be a subview of the label.

If they share the same superview, you can position the image view behind the label, and it should appear "through" the label as long as the label's background is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way to do.....
You can add `UIImageView`, `UILabel` as subview of `cell.textLabel`

```
UIImageView *statusImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, 8, 8)];<br/>statusImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];<br/>
statusImage.layer.cornerRadius = 4;<br/>
statusImage.clipsToBounds = YES;<br/>
[cell.textLabel addSubview:statusImage];<br/>

UILabel *Lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, cell.textLabel.frame.size.width - 15, cell.textLabel.frame.size.height)];<br/>
Lbl.text = @"xyz";<br/>
[cell.textLabel addSubview:Lbl];<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem as well. 
I found that ImageView was behind the label.
When I replaced label with UIView, it works properly.